# How can apportable build to generate a share object(.so) file instead of api file?

Tags: apportable

Is there a way to generate a shared object file instead of a AKP file, if I build a static library Xcode project? If it can be done, how to invoke the exported function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apportable build process

1. Creates an archive file of your app - lib{appname}.a
2. Links it along with some system objects into an so - libverde.so
3. Packages and zips libverde.so, other .so's and various Android resources into - {appname}.apk

You can modify this process by changing the python scripts in ~/.apportable/SDK/site_scons